# Trigger to compare date SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am new in SQL Server and doing a homework.

I have a table Booking_Details(Booking_ID, Date_From, Date_To, Room_Number, Hotel_ID)

I want to create a trigger to compare Date_From and Date_to before inserting or updating on database. I am trying a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_date ON Booking_Details
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
IF (UPDATE(Date_To) OR UPDATE(Date_From))
BEGIN
DECLARE @Date_From DATE, @Date_To DATE
SET @Date_From=(SELECT Date_From FROM Booking_Details)
SET @Date_To=(SELECT Date_To FROM Booking_Details)
IF(@Date_From>@Date_To)
    BEGIN
    PRINT "Date To must larger than Date From"
    END
    END
```

But when i test it return

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: You need to look into `INSERTED` table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several flaws...

You have to change this

```
SET @Date_From=(SELECT Date_From FROM Booking_Details)
SET @Date_To=(SELECT Date_To FROM Booking_Details)
```

to this

```
SET @Date_From=(SELECT Date_From FROM inserted)
SET @Date_To=(SELECT Date_To FROM inserted)
```

The table 'inserted' is a structurally identical "table" containing the rows of the actual process.

Your attempt to set the variable's value with `=(SELECT Date_From FROM inserted)` will work with one single row only!

### BUT

You must be aware, that a trigger must be able to deal with more than one row at once. This approach would break, if you insert or update more than one row...

Are you allowed to use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` instead of this trigger? This would be much easier...

Maybe a bit simpler like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_date ON Booking_Details
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
IF (UPDATE(Date_To) OR UPDATE(Date_From)) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE Date_From>DateTo)
    --Do something (I'd suggest RAISERROR)

END
```

`IF EXISTS(SELECT ...)` will be true, **if any of the inserted/updated rows** is invalid. You might even let the `(UPDATE(Date_To) OR UPDATE(Date_From))` away...

**About `RAISERROR`** [find details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Comment: Is this work when i try to update things? Well i have to write trigger and procedure ^_^

Comment: @notmeanymore Sorry, don't understand your comment. Did you check my last update?

Comment: s/ERRAISE/RAISERROR

Comment: @Shnugo not till now. It already met my requirement, i wondering what trigger usally do when a condition fail, i have no idea what is ERRAISE ..

Comment: @notmeanymore You're welcome. An alternative is to [THROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ee677615.aspx) an error.

Comment: @TT. Thx, sure, it's `RAISERROR`. This word is missing an "E", while `ERRAISE` was missing an "R" :-) That's why I muddled this up :-))